# Alternative for HP ALM (QC) + Jira

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, quality-center, jira

For a semi-large company that plans to move away from HP ALM, I'm looking for an alternative software management tool. At the moment HP ALM is not being used optimally and since it's expensive it's being phased out.

The company has around 20 projects running, and there are probably a hundred testers busy at any given time with manual testing, but also running acceptance and regression tests on several environments. New releases ship every two weeks.

The testers however are very used to working with ALM, and don't really want to change their ways.

Do you know of a test management tool that has similar features (requirement tracking all the way from test case creation up to defects, testing libraries for test reuse and tree file views) that integrates well with JIRA?

So far I have been looking at XQual, Zephyr for JIRA and TestRail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had the same issue here (we had less users than you though).

We found all JIRA's plugins not enough (very far from what QC/ALM gives). They may be good enough for simple manual testing and if you don't need evoluated features. But if you comes from ALM it will be really a downgrade.

For us, TestRail was better than all the JIRA plugins but still, it was missing some fundamental features and the GUI was really different from ALM.

At the end we went with XStudio. Not perfect in terms of ergonomy but this is definitely what looks the more like QC/ALM. after 6 month, I must admit that I tend to even prefer it to QC/ALM. The price is pretty good and there are often new versions. So far so good.

Maike

Answer (score 0):

We are using TestRail and Jira and usually have around 10 concurrent projects. We are about to upgrade to TestRail v5 to take advantage of the extended Jira integration.

Answer (score 0):

If the testers are used to QC/ALM interface, they would find [Silk Central](http://www.borland.com/en-GB/Products/Software-Testing/Test-Management/Silk-Central) very intuitive, because they are very similar. It has out-of-the-box integration with both JIRA Agile (for user story/requirement coverage) and JIRA issue tracker.

Manual testing supports offline execution, screenshot and video capture, scripts with visual assets to help the tester, shared steps libraries...

On the automation side, it is integrated with JUnit, NUnit, Silk Test, Windows Scripting, and command line, among others; supporting Keyword Driven Testing to ease reuse.

Free 45-day trials can be downloaded from http://www.borland.com/en-GB/Products/Software-Testing/Test-Management/Silk-Central/Product-Trial

Answer (score 0):

I work for IT Central Station, and you might find some of the real user reviews on our site to be helpful.

You can see all major alternative to HP ALM on IT Central Station, with user reviews details why they chose each solution to help you make your decision. http://www.itcentralstation.com/categories/application-lifecycle-management-suites

It's worth noting that when it comes to HP ALM, several user reviews have noted that they evaluated other solutions, including TFS, IBM CLM, Jira Grasshopper and more, and decided to stay with ALM based on factors including ease of use, and integration with other tools. You can read their reviews here: http://www.itcentralstation.com/products/hp-alm

Comment: Hi Naomi - two problems. First, affiliation has to be announced in every post that promotes the product you're affiliated with (which you did in your last post, but not here). Second, it is hard to accept an answer that basically says "follow this link, it has your answer". But I'm going to have to do some soul searching about this entire question, honestly - I'm not sure whether it should even be open, because it doesn't appear to be answerable (despite the accepted answer).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited to include affiliation, and I'll make sure it is in all future posts. I leave the soul searching to you ;-) Happy Holidays!

Comment: Warning:  IT Central Station link above is a "bait and switch" email trap. They suggest emailing you free whitepaper, but to get it you need to provide (1) email, which is OK, and (2) extensive review of what you use, which will be submitted under your name. So basically **they harvest email for free (no whitepaper)**, unless you want to spend significant time writing the review, what they do not disclose upfront. Sadly, I upvoted the answer and cannot revert it now.

Answer (score 0):

Restyboard and ZenTao.

Both open source and codes on GitHub

Easy for customization and integration.